# assign std::unique_ptr to std::function

Tags: c++11

There is a custom defined map, with an element std::function()>.
The lambda code is working, but I don't know how to expand it to a normal formation. The code is following.

```
class TestA{
public:
    TestA() {}
    ~TestA() {}

    TestA(const TestA &) {}

    static void print()
    {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return;
    }
};

void testComplexMap1()
{

    typedef map<string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<TestA>()>> TempMap;
    TempMap m;
    // the lambda format code, it works
    //m.insert({ "TestA", []() {return std::unique_ptr<TestA>(new TestA());}});

    // I want to expand it, but failed.
    TestA *t = new TestA();
    //function<unique_ptr<TestA>()> fp(unique_ptr<TestA>(t));
    function<unique_ptr<TestA>()> fp(unique_ptr<TestA>(t)()); //warning here
    //m.emplace("TestA", fp);              // compile error here
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`fp` is not initialized with a function so compilation fails.

You can expand it like this:

```
TestA *t = new TestA();
std::unique_ptr<TestA> UT(t);   
auto func = [&]() { return move(UT);};
std::function<std::unique_ptr<TestA>()> fp(func);
m.emplace("TestA", fp);
```

See [**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/iQpLrI).

Comment: Thanks, it works. And I understand it now. You define "func" to get the unique_ptr, and it is callable, so it could be assigned to std::funtion.

Comment: @wade: you're welcome. `std::function` should have a target (callable) without which it cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ everything that looks like it could be a declaration is treated as such.
This means the line

```
function<unique_ptr<TestA>()> fp(unique_ptr<TestA>(t)());
```

is interpreted as:
`fp` is the declaration of a function returning an `std::function<unique_ptr<TestA>()>` and expecting a parameter called `t` which is a function pointer to a function returning a `std::unique_ptr<TestA>` and getting no parameter. (Which is not what you intended.)

This also means that the `t` in this line is not the same `t` as in the previous line.

You have to pass `fp` something that is actually callable like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<TestA> f() {    
    return std::make_unique<TestA>();
}

void testComplexMap1() {
    // ...
    function<unique_ptr<TestA>()> fp(f);
    m.emplace("TestA1", fp);  
}
```

If you want to add a function to the map that wraps an existing pointer into a `unique_ptr` you would need either a functor:

```
class Functor {
public:
    Functor(TestA * a) : m_a(a) {}
    ~Functor() { delete m_a; }

    std::unique_ptr<TestA> operator()(){
        auto x = std::unique_ptr<TestA>(m_a);
        m_a = nullptr;
        return std::move(x);
    }

private:
    TestA * m_a;
};

void testComplexMap1() {
    //...
    TestA * t = new TestA();
    m.emplace("TestA", Functor(t));  
}
```

Or a lambda with capture:

```
void testComplexMap1() {
    //...
    TestA * t = new TestA();
    m.emplace("TestA", [t](){ return std::unique_ptr<TestA>(t); });  
}
```

The lamda is translated more or less to something like the `Functor` class. However in each case you have to be really careful: The functions in the map that encapsulate an existing pointer into a `std::unique_ptr` can and should only be called once.

If you don't call them, memory allocated for `t` won't be freed. If you call them more than once you get either a `std::unique_ptr` to `nullptr` (in my `Functor` class variant) or a more than one `std::unique_ptr` tries to manage the same memory region (in the lambda with capture variant), which will crash as soon as the second `std::unique_ptr` is deleted.

In short: I would advice against writing code like this and only put functions in the map that are callable multiple times.